# How to convert list of enums into array of strings?

Tags: java

I've had an array of enums like below:

```
enum CountryEnum {
   MADAGASCAR,
   LESOTHO,
   BAHAMAS,
   TURKEY,
   UAE
}

List<CountryEnum> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
countryList.add(CountryEnum.MADAGASCAR);
countryList.add(CountryEnum.BAHAMAS);
```

How to convert my `countryList` into `String[]`?

I've tried this way:

```
String[] countries = countryList.toArray(String::new);
```

but it returned me `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: did you really get that error? or is the posted code wrong, missing the second `[]` like in `String[] countries = countryList.toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work so:

```java
 String[] strings = countryList.stream() // create Stream of enums from your list
                    .map(Enum::toString) // map each enum to desired string (here we take simple toString() for each enum)
                    .toArray(String[]::new); // collect it into string array
```

Comment: the answer is correct, but it could benefit from some clarification as to why it is done this way

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
enum CountryEnum {
   MADAGASCAR("Madagascar"),
   LESOTHO("Lesotho"),
   BAHAMAS("Bahamas"),
   TURKEY("Turkey"),
   UAE("UAE");

    String country;
    CountryEnum(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
}
```

I added a constructor to be able to get (in String) enum's values. Now you can just use:

```
List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
countryList.add(CountryEnum.MADAGASCAR.getCountry());
countryList.add(CountryEnum.BAHAMAS.getCountry());
```